# How to remove link from magento site top navigation subcategories?

Tags: magento, navigation

How to remove link from magento site top navigation subcategories. I want subcategories should be there but it should not be click able.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "fast way" to do it.You need to create a new module, to override the existing one and change the way that categories are printed through magento.